# Jenkins: Limit Credentials to 'Manage Jenkins > Configure System'

Tags: jenkins, github, webhooks, pull-request

We would like to use the GitHub Pull Request Builder plugin in Jenkins, however in order to use this plugin you are required to enter credentials in the 'Manage Jenkins > Configure System' section that gives access to a given GitHub Enterprise server.

Our issue is that credentials giving access to all of github are too strong to be stored in the credentials manager. I know that you can limit the scope of credentials by using the Folders plugin, however this just limits access to those credentials to jobs in certain folders. Is there a way to restrict credentials so they can only be used in the 'Manage Jenkins > Configure System' section?

Comment: No, there isn't. And @bitoiu gave you the next best thing. A personal access token with reduced scopes is what you need. If you only need to clone and build, I don't think you'll need the admin permissions for that. One thing you could look into is whether it's possible to develop your own plugin to implement a credential type that can only be used in the global configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Our issue is that credentials giving access to all of github are too strong to be stored in the credentials manager.

This is why you can also use a [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line). Check the documentation for the plugin at: https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/plugins/pull-request-builder-for-github/. This is not the official plugin page but having read both, this one keeps to the best practices in terms of credentials. The important bits are:

1. Go to your GitHub settings page.
2. In the left sidebar, click Personal Access Token.
3. Click Generate new token.
4. Give your token a descriptive name
5. Select the scopes to grant to this token. Pull request tester plugin require permission to administer repository hooks and access repositories: `repo`, `public_repo`, `admin:repo_hook`, `repo:status`.

Then you can follow the rest of the guide to enter the token in the plugin configuration pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. Unfortunately my problem isn't with keeping a password in the password manager. Even if the credential is in the form of a personal access token, it will be available to anyone to use. Because the pull request builder requires access to all repositories on our github server, we need to be able to limit who can use that credential to prevent everyone having access to all repositories.

Comment: Our issue is that credentials giving access to all of github are too strong to be stored in the credentials manager.

There's no option then because Jenkins does not support Apps or the plugin doesn't work with GitHub Apps. My answer was directly pointing at your comment above. A username/password is completely diff from a PAT in what rights it gives. First of all the scope is reduced and there's destructive actions that you can't do with the PAT, but only through the WebUI, so that's your best choice.

Comment: This is in fact the next best thing to what is being asked —short of developing your own type of credential plugin and somehow restricting where it can be used. I don't get why it was voted down. An answer should not be voted down just because it's not the answer you want, especially when the answer you want is not feasible. I've voted it up to compensate.